# [PHP][Laravel][AJAX] Dropdown Cascade / Dependent Dropdown using Select2 and AJAX Not Working

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, jquery-select2

I'm trying to create a dependent dropdown using Select2. I've been following this tutorial :

https://ilmukita.org/laravel-8-membuat-dynamic-dependent-dropdown-menggunakan-select2/

When i'm trying to select my **group service** (parent) the **service** (child) option not showing up, any idea to show my service option ? Here's my code :

[1] Route

```js
Route::controller(TaskController::class)->prefix('dashboard/task')->middleware(['role:admin|operator|user-bisnis|user-qa'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'index');
    Route::get('/create', 'create')->name('task.create');
    Route::post('/', 'store')->name('task.store');
    Route::get('/edit/{id}', 'edit')->name('task.edit');
    Route::post('/update/{id}', 'update')->name('task.update');
    Route::post('/delete/{id}', 'destroy')->name('task.delete');
    Route::get('/groupservice', 'getGroupService')->name('groupservice.select'); //
    Route::get('/service', 'getService')->name('service.select'); //
});
```

[2] Controller

```js
public function getService(Request $request)
    {
        $service = [];
        $groupserviceID = $request->groupserviceID;
        if ($request->has('q')) {
            $search = $request->q;
            $service = Service::select("id", "nama")
                ->where('gruplayanan_id', $groupserviceID)
                ->Where('deskripsi', 'LIKE', "%$search%")
                ->get();
        } else {
            $service = Service::where('gruplayanan_id', $groupserviceID)->limit(10)->get();
        }
        return response()->json($service);
    }
```

[3] View

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

      $('#gruplayanan_id').change(function() {
        //clear select
        $("#layanan_id").empty();
        //set id
        let groupserviceID = $(this).val();
        if (groupserviceID) {
            $('#layanan_id').select2({
              allowClear: true,
              ajax: {
                  url: "{{ route('service.select') }}?groupserviceID=" + groupserviceID,
                  dataType: 'json',
                  delay: 250,
                  processResults: function(data) {
                    return {
                        results: $.map(data, function(item) {
                          return {
                              text: item.nama,
                              id: item.id
                          }
                        })
                    };
                  }
              }
            });
        }
      });

    $('#gruplayanan_id').on('select2:clear', function(e) {
      $("#layanan_id").select2();
    });
  });
```

```html
<head>
{{-- Select2 --}}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/css/select2.min.css">
  
</head>

<body>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="gruplayanan" class="form-label">Pilih Group Layanan</label><span style="color: red;">*</span>
          <select class="theSelect" name="gruplayanan_id" id="gruplayanan_id" style="width: 300px" autofocus required>
            <option hidden></option>
              @foreach ($groupservice as $item => $groupservice)
                <option value="{{ $groupservice->id }}">{{ $groupservice->deskripsi }}</option>
              @endforeach
          </select>
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="layanan" class="form-label">Pilih Layanan</label><span style="color: red;">*</span>
          <select class="theSelect" name="layanan_id" id="layanan_id" style="width: 300px" autofocus required>
          </select>
      </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi it just wont show up the depedent field (the child) option after i select (parent) option

Comment: What does AJAX Request return?

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi how to check this sir? i'm very new in Laravel and AJAX

Comment: Open your network tab and check what does the request return

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution, it seems the Jquery and Library for Select2 in my project, has problem / issues !. For example i cant wrap my class in Select2 with `$(document).ready(function() {}` 
function, so i tried to defer my CDN in `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js" defer></script>` 
and it WORKS !!